# Can electrical noise cancel itself out?

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise

If two independent noise sources are added together, their noise adds up like so:

$$RMS_{sum} = \sqrt{RMS_1^2 + RMS_2^2}$$

Am I correct to assume that this only holds if the noise sources are independent?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foImVu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For example in this circuit (assume that R1 is the only noise source), the noise is buffered by OA1 and then inverted by OA2. The resistors R5 and R6 sum the two signals together. In this case, the noise of R1 should not appear at the output, correct?

That is, I **cannot** calculate the noise of the output of the two op amps independently and then add them up with \$RMS_{out} = \sqrt{RMS_{OA1}^2 + RMS_{OA2}^2}\$.

Comment: Given the restriction that all of the components are the right produce absolutely no noise, have no parasitic properties, no distortion, and infinite bandwidth, I think your statement is correct. However, if you tried to build this circuit, it would result in increased noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct about the equation's restrictions. The words you are looking for are correlated and uncorrelated noise. That equation is for valid uncorrelated noise sources only.

But it's a tall order to have all the noise sources in a circuit to be of the correlated variety, let alone be correlated in such that they match so perfectly and in exactly the right way so as to completely cancel each other out. It's kind of like hoping the random quantum motion of all particles in your starship just happen to all continuously be in the same direction so that you move forward with no fuel.

Indeed, correlation could lead to the noise being higher than that indicated by your equation.